# how to authenticate google app script with GAE application using OAuth 2.0 [ GAS and GAE ]

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have developed the application it will interact with GAE application from GAS script using OAuth 1.0 but we couldn't made it with with OAuth 2.0 we are getting access failure from OAuth.

The getservice.hasAccess() always returns false. I am highly confused on which URL I have to use for authentication process.

I have attached the source for Oauth 1 and OAuth 2 for reference

```
Oauth 1.0
=========
envVars.url = myapp.appspot.com;

  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(envVars.serviceName);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl(envVars.url + '/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken');
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl(envVars.url + '/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken');
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl(envVars.url + '/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken');

  var requestData = {
    "oAuthServiceName": envVars.serviceName,
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
  };

  requestData.muteHttpExceptions = true;




Oauth 2.0
=========

envVars.url = myapp.appspot.com
 getservice = getService();


 if (getservice.hasAccess()) {
    Logger.log("All OK");
    return;
  }
 else {
    var authorizationUrl = getservice.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
               authorizationUrl);
    showURL(authorizationUrl);
  }

function getService()
{
   return OAuth2.createService(envVars.serviceName)
  // Set the endpoint URLs.
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(envVars.url + '/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken')
  .setTokenUrl(envVars.url + '/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken')               


  // Set the client ID and secret.
  .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
  .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

  // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to complete
  // the OAuth flow.
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be mindful that OAuth 1.0 was officially deprecated last April 20, 2012. It is suggested that you need to migrate  [OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth_ref) as soon as possible.

If a script uses services that can access private data, you will encounter authorization dialog. Apps Script determine the authorization scopes.

Scripts that you have previously authorized will also ask for additional authorization if a code change adds new services. Scripts do not request authorization if they use only services that cannot access user data

Check this document which discuss Permissions and types of scripts: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts

Comment: Hi Datul, Thanks for your reply but i have implemented the code for OAuth2 I am having trouble on which URL have to use for GAE authentication .